# How to plot similar cluster side by side?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, visualization, plotly-python

I plotted a cluster , and i want the same image side by side, can anybody tell me how to do that?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Prepare data
umap_data = umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=15, n_components=2, min_dist=0.0, metric='cosine').fit_transform(model_embeddings1)
result = pd.DataFrame(umap_data, columns=['x', 'y'])
result['labels'] = cluster_model1.labels_

# Visualize clusters
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
outliers = result.loc[result.labels == -1, :]
clustered = result.loc[result.labels != -1, :]
plt.scatter(outliers.x, outliers.y, color='#BDBDBD', s=0.05)
plt.scatter(clustered.x, clustered.y, c=clustered.labels, s=0.05, cmap='hsv_r')
plt.colorbar()..
```

I just need the same figure by its side.[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "The same image side by side"? Can you produce an example of the desired output to help us help you? :)

Comment: Hi, i meant something like this, where the output image can be seen side by side, didn't know how to show, https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/clustering/algorithm/advantages-disadvantages     , something like the first image.

Comment: So, basically you need to know how to show 2 images side by side in a Colab Notebook?
I mean: you already got the images you want to show and your problem is how to show them side by side?

Comment: yes exactly, thats what i want.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly your question you need to change the code under `# Visualize clusters` with something like this:

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
f.set_figheight(20)
f.set_figwidth(10)
outliers = result.loc[result.labels == -1, :]
clustered = result.loc[result.labels != -1, :]
ax1.scatter(outliers.x, outliers.y, color='#BDBDBD', s=0.05)
ax2.scatter(clustered.x, clustered.y, c=clustered.labels, s=0.05, 
cmap='hsv_r')
```

Comment: I understood the concept of ax, but this seem to give me the first image empty, any idea where am i going wrong here?:(

Comment: Not knowing the data i cannot help you in  this, i'm sorry. 
Try to plot `outliers` and `clustered` data separately and/or check the content of `result` dataframe and make sure that `outliers` isn't empty.
But that's another question and if you found my answer useful please consider to accept it :)